# How can I switch between 2 Ajax functions with a setTimeout in each function in jQuery / JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, settimeout

I have 2 Ajax functions, each reading in a set of numbers. This is just a demo so assuming the syntax is correct and all data loads correctly. Each function has a setTimeout that reloads the data in every 2 seconds.

I am trying to switch between the 2 functions which I can do but I cannot seem to stop the timeout from firing when I switch. Both timeouts fire simultaneously.

Here is the HTML file -

```
<button class="btn low-btn">Get Low Numbers</button>
<button class="btn high-btn">Get High Numbers</button>

<div class="numbers"></div>

<script src="data.js"></script>
```

Here is the data.js file -

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var timeout_high;
    var timeout_low;

    function low() {
        $.ajax('get-low.php', {
            success: function (data) {
                $(".numbers").replaceWith("<div class='numbers'>Low Numbers: "+data+"</div>");
                var timeout_low = setTimeout(low, 2000);
           } 
       });
    }

  function high() {
        $.ajax('get-high.php', {
           success: function (data) {
              $(".numbers").replaceWith("<div class='numbers'>High Numbers: "+data+"</div>");
              var timeout_high = setTimeout(high, 2000);
           } 
       });
    }



    $(".low-btn").click(function(){
         clearTimeout(timeout_high);
         low();
    });


    $(".high-btn").click(function(){
        clearTimeout(timeout_low);
        high();
    });

});
```

I try and use clearTimeout once a button is clicked but it doesn't kill the timeout but both functions are continue to fire. If I keep clicking it just keeps adding more timeouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both lines below:

```
var timeout_low = setTimeout(low, 2000);
var timeout_high = setTimeout(high, 2000);
```

... instead of assigning new values to the variables defined right at the beginning of `$(document).ready` function create *new ones*, local to the corresponding functions. Hence clearTimeouts actually do nothing - they run outside of the ajax:success handlers, and see only 'outer' variables.

*(and yes, `clearTimeout(undefined)` neither throws nor warns)*

The easiest solution would be dropping `var` from those statements:

```
timeout_low = setTimeout(low, 2000);
timeout_high = setTimeout(high, 2000);
```

Still, I'd strongly consider merging those functions into a single one, using some kind of dictionary, tying together data fetchers and the elements their results should be displayed in.

Comment: Yep that was it Thank you!

Comment: Great idea regarding wrapping this in a main function